# Consultar desde Access a un archivo Excel publicado en SharePoint

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, excel-2013, ms-access-2013

Tengo la siguiente consulta en Excel:

```
=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(I21;'https://cmconsultores.sharepoint.com/sites/POST-OPERACIONAL/Documentos compartidos/5. Informes semanales/7. Del 18 de julio al 24 de julio de 2022/INSUMOS SEMANA 29/VALIDACIONES/[Consolidado Validaciones semana 29.xlsx]Hoja1'!$U:$Y;5;0);0)
```

La cual paso a Access mediante una consulta que es la siguiente :

VALIDACIONES:

```
IIF(IsError(dlookup([ConcatenarValidaciones];'https://cmconsultores.sharepoint.com/sites/POST-OPERACIONAL/Documentos compartidos/
5. Informes semanales/7. Del 18 de julio al 24 de julio de 2022/INSUMOS SEMANA 29/
VALIDACIONES/[Consolidado Validaciones semana 29.xlsx]Hoja1'!$U:$Y,5,0),0)
```

Al ejecutar la consulta me muestra el compilador de Access error en el operador !, del segmento de consulta Hoja1'

con base a lo anterior, mi pregunta es que si yo puedo realizar una consulta de esta índole en Access haciendo referencia a un  archivo de Excel publicado en Sharepoint.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.